# How to change andorid layout as per image given below

Tags: android

Currently my listview design looks like [image]

But I want to make it look like below image 
[image]

Where image will be on right hand side, title in Bold and Subtitle just below it. What changes do I need to make in my layout, Below is my code. Thanks in 
advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tom Cruise"
                android:textColor="#166CED"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />



        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescriptionn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#009A57"
        android:text="Description" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Changing position of the image views and putting in margins will do the trick.

Comment: In my opinion better use `GridLayout` for better performance :).
P.S. Start think, dont look for someone who will do it for you.

Comment: will the image will be below the heading ? or on top right corner ?

Comment: @SagarNayak - yes below heading and next to description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better result to manage your view use relativelayout.
   You can manage your layout as example give below-
   [image: Screenshot]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="4dp"
android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/grey">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrow"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Murdochs needed counselling after hacking scandle says magazine"
            android:textColor="#166CED"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSubtitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivImage"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="NEW YORK:The British phone hacking scandle"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks but what if i don't want to use widget card?

Comment: Its very simple just replace it@user45678

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use relative layout . this will make your layout more flexible to edit. I have suggested a layout below , give it a try .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Tom Cruse"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#166CED" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDescriptionn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivImage"
    android:text="Description"
    android:textColor="#009A57" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please do accept this answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use flowTextView jar to your project. Here you can find the jar:
https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView

Answer (score -1):

Inside LinearLayout, place textview at the top to show the title. Make height wrap_content and width match_parent.

Below this, add linearlayout which contains textview and image. set orientation horizontal to inner liner layout.

For better placing you can always used relative layout. for example

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.testlayout.MainActivity" >

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/titleText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/descriptionText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titleText"
    android:text="description"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titleText"
   android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rightArrow"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/rightArrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titleText"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />



</RelativeLayout>
```